# What does this syntax really do int i = 1 | 2 ; bool b = false | true;

Tags: c#, .net

I am confused why we can use `'or'(|)`  operator in statments like `int i = 1 | 2 ;   bool b = false | true;`
and what does this syntax really do ? and when is this syntax useful , can someone please enlighten mean about that syntax ?

Comment: [Bit wise operations in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1544/Bit-wise-operations-in-C)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is bitwise OR operator which does digital ORing between 2 values like 1 has binary value 0001 and 2 has binary value 0010, so if you write 1 | 2 then it will return 0011 value which is 3.

For bool, it does boolean OR, i.e. gives false only if both the operands are false.

It is defined for bool and integral types. It can also be overloaded for user defined types. Have a look here at [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/kxszd0kx.aspx).

Comment: so what about    bool b = false | true;  ?

Comment: for bools, it is false if both values are false, else its true

Comment: @Serv actually the same binary rules apply. You can construct two bools of internal values 1 and 2 that when ANDed combine to false. That's rare because C# does not allow you to control that, but IL does.

Comment: I just remembered this from the top of my head. Had it in my first semester at university from Borel algebra.

Answer (score 1):

**Bit OR**

```
1 = 0000 0001
2 = 0000 0010
1|2 = 0000 0011
```

**OR Table**

```
A B A|B
0 1  1
0 0  0
1 0  1
1 1  1
```

**Use Case**

BitWise OR is used to set the perticular bit.

**Example :** 
Suppose we have to set bit 2 in 0000 0001

> 0000 0001 | 0000 0100 = 0000 0101

Comment: what about bool b = false | true ?

Answer (score 1):

Since the integer question is answered already:

For bool values, like `bool x = true | false` `x is true`.

It is false, if both operants are false, and only BOTH. Everything else returns true

```
 true | false  => true
false | true => true
 true | true => true

false | false => false
```